# Is there a way to return hyperparameters tuned by Pycaret?

Tags: python, machine-learning, hyperparameters, pycaret

Pycaret automatically searches the best parameters. For example, the codes below will allocate 5 automatically tuned models to 'tuned_top5'.

```
from pycaret.classification import *
setup(data=train, train_size=.9, target='my_target_feature')
tuned_top5 = [tune_model(model) for model in top5]
```

However, this is not enough for me. I want to know the exact names and values of hyperparameters. For instance, if this code tune max_depth to 9, I want "max_depth=9" or similar outcome to be printed.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can pull out the names of the parameters from the models and print them out directly:

```
print(tuned_top5.get_all_params())
```

If you are only interested in a single parameter, or a short list of parameters then pull them out individually to print.

```
params = tuned_top5.get_all_params()
print("max depth = ', params['max_depth'])
```

Comment: It is always better to add a description to the code you post, so it is well explained and informative.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know is it your question but;

```
best=compare_models(exclude=['ransac'])
```

best variable gets most succesfully model for regression its default r2 so just use;

```
print(best)
```

so you can see which parameters used by this model.you can also see all hypermeters when you save models or you can print model you manually created with pycaret.
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
tuned_best_model.get_params
```

And it will give you the list with the hyperparameters that were chosen in the tuning.

I hope it helps you.